# Is there any software on ubuntu to float my screenshot on the screen, like the snappy for mac?

Tags: 18.04, screenshot

As the title explained, I'm eager to find an alternative software on Ubuntu which can make my screenshot floating on the screen, just like the snappy application on macOS.

But after googling for a while I didn't manage to get a good answer. Would you like to give me some advice?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In the link you should check out Spectacle as it might be something very similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Terrance for this quick reply! It solved my problem. Do I needs to delete this problem now?

Comment: Nah, you can leave it here in case someone else comes along asking the same question it can help point them in the right direction.  =)